# Django admin panel permissions: preventing user group from adding more users

Tags: python, django

I want to restrict my worker users' admin panel - don't want them to create users or delete certain types of models, for instance.

Here's some code in `models.py` that sets up my custom user, and the `post_save` signal to add users.

Note that I set `default_permissions = ()` so that users don't start with any permissions, but then I grant them the permissions of the group with `name=workers` which does NOT include `myapp.myuser_add`, thus they **shouldn't** be able to add more users when logged into admin console.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Group
)
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def apply_worker_group(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_worker:
        try:
            worker_group = Group.objects.get(name='workers') 
            if instance not in worker_group.user_set.all():
                instance.groups.add(worker_group)
                instance.save()
        except Group.DoesNotExist:
            pass

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_worker = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    # ... skipping a bunch of stuff

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = () # (!) ALL USERS HAVE NO PERMS TO START

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        # so workers can log into the admin panel
        return self.is_admin or self.is_worker
```

Then in my `admin.py`:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import MyUser

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    pass

class MyAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    pass

admin_site = MyAdminSite(name='myadmin')
admin_site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

But when I create a user under my superuser account with `is_worker=True`, I can still log in with that created user to admin panel and create more users! Which is not what I want.

Any suggestions for how to restrict user permissions using groups like this?